# List of Objects into an Crate Array

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement a Beverage Crate array that will be filled by a list of beverages, but I have problem creating the array. I have tried to do some temporary solutions in the program but I can't get them to work since the crate array won't work. The problem is in the Crate Class and the main class, where the add-beverage method doesn't work.

How do I get my array to work while not using a list for the crate? 
  One of the errors I get is  here

```
{
            if (crate.Count >= MaxItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The crate is full. Please remove an item first!");
            }
            else
            {
                crate.Add(beverage);
```

I get a compile error operand of >= cannot be applied to method group of type int and beverage does not contain a definition for Add in crate.add line

```
class Menu : Crate
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                ShowMenu(); // Wait for input before closing
                Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            public static void ShowMenu()
            {
                bool exit = false;
                var beverages = new Crate();
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[1] Add Bottle from existing list to Bottle Crate");// TODO IMPLEMENT 
                    Console.WriteLine("[2] Remove Bottle from Bottle Crate");
                    Console.WriteLine("[3] Show Bottle Crate");// TODO IMPLEMENT
                    Console.WriteLine("[4] Add custom beverage to array");
                    Console.WriteLine("[5] Remove Beverage from list"); // TODO
                    Console.WriteLine("[6] Sort Bottles in Bottle Crate according to name");// TODO IMPLEMENT
                    Console.WriteLine("[7] AutoFill crate"); 
                    Console.WriteLine("[8] Calculate the Total Cost in Crate"); // TODO IMPLEMENT
                    Console.WriteLine("[9] Search in crate after beverage");   // TODO IMPLEMENT
                    Console.WriteLine("[0] Exit the program");

                    ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey();
                    int selection;
                    int.TryParse(info.KeyChar.ToString(), out selection);

                    switch (selection)
                    {
                        case 1:

                            break;
                        case 2:
                            //beverages.Remove();
                            //break;
                        case 3:
                            Console.WriteLine("\nHere are the contents of the crate:\n");
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                            beverages.PrintCrate();
                            Console.ResetColor();
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            var numBevs = Math.Max(GetInt("How many beverages would you like to enter: "), 0);

                            for (int i = 0; i < numBevs; i++)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"\nEnter beverage #{i + 1} info");
                                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");
                                beverages.Add(Beverages.GetBeverageFromUser());
                                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------\n");
                            }
                            break;
                        //case 5:
                        //    Remove_Beverage();
                        //    break;
                        //case 6:
                        //    SortCrate();
                        //    break;
                        case 7:
                            numBevs = Math.Max(GetInt("How many would you like to be auto-added: "), 0);

                            for (int i = 0; i < numBevs; i++)
                            {
                                beverages.Add(Beverages.GetRandomBeverage());
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------\n");
                            break;
                        //case 8:
                        //    Calc_Total();
                        //    break;
                        //case 9:
                        //    //SearchArray();
                        //    break;
                        case 0:
                            exit = true;
                            break;
                        default:
                            ShowMenu();
                            break;
                    }

                    } while (!exit) ;
                }
            }
        }


    class Crate : IEnumerable<Beverage>
        {
            private Beverage[] crate = new Beverage[24];
            private int numberOfBottles = 0;

            private const int MaxItems = 24;
            public void Add(Beverage beverage)
            {
                if (crate.Count >= MaxItems)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The crate is full. Please remove an item first!");
                }
                else
                {
                    crate.Add(beverage);
                }
            }
            public IEnumerator<Beverage> GetEnumerator()
            {
                return crate.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
            }

            IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return GetEnumerator();
            }

            public void Remove(string name)
            {
                Remove(crate.FirstOrDefault(i =>
                    i.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
            }

            public void Remove(Beverage beverage)
            {
                if (crate.Contains(beverage)) crate.Remove(beverage);
            }

            public void PrintCrate()
            {
                if (crate.Count == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There are no items in the crate.");
                }
                else
                {
                    crate.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                }
            }
            //public int find_Soda(string drinkname)
            //{
            //    for (int i = 0; i < bottles.Length; i++)
            //    {
            //        if (bottles[i].Drink_name == drinkname) //My feeble attempts
            //            return i;
            //    }
            //    return -1;
            //}
            //public void sort_Sodas_name()
            //{
            //    int max = bottles.Length;
            //    //Outer loop for complete [bottles]
            //    for (int i = 1; i < max; i++)
            //    {
            //        //Inner loop for row by row
            //        int nrLeft = max - i;
            //        for (int j = 0; j < (max - i); j++)
            //        {
            //            var bottle1 = bottles[j];
            //            var bottle2 = bottles[j + 1];

            //            if ((bottle1 == null) || (bottle2 == null))
            //            {
            //                continue;
            //            }
            //            if (bottle1.name.CompareTo(bottle2.Drink_name) == 1)
            //            {
            //                var temp = bottles[j];
            //                bottles[j] = bottles[j + 1];
            //                bottles[j + 1] = temp;

            //public int calc_total()
            //{
            //    int temp = 0;
            //    for (int i = 0; i < bottleCount(); i++)
            //    {
            //        temp = temp + (bottles[i].Price);
            //    }
            //    return temp;

            public static int GetInt(string message)
            {
                int result;
                Console.Write(message);

                while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid number");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.Write(message);
                }

                return result;
            }
        }
    }




     public class Beverages
        {
            private static readonly Random Rnd = new Random();

            public static Beverage GetBeverageFromUser()
            {
                return new Beverage
                {
                    Name = GetName("Enter name: "),
                    Price = GetCurrency("Enter cost: "),
                    Type = GetBeverageType("Enter type: "),
                    Size = GetSize("Enter size: ")
                };
            }

            public static Beverage GetRandomBeverage()
            {
                var names = new List<Beverage>
            {
                new Beverage {Name = "Coke", Price = .75m,
                    Size = 12, Type = BeverageType.Soda},
                new Beverage {Name = "Pepsi", Price = .75m,
                    Size = 12, Type = BeverageType.Soda},
                new Beverage {Name = "Sprite", Price = .75m,
                    Size = 12, Type = BeverageType.Soda},
                new Beverage {Name = "Rootbeer", Price = .75m,
                    Size = 12, Type = BeverageType.Soda},
                new Beverage {Name = "Orange Juice", Price = .5m,
                    Size = 10, Type = BeverageType.Juice},
                new Beverage {Name = "Apple Juice", Price = .5m,
                    Size = 10, Type = BeverageType.Juice},
                new Beverage {Name = "Grape Juice", Price = .5m,
                    Size = 10, Type = BeverageType.Juice},
                new Beverage {Name = "Water", Price = .25m,
                    Size = 20, Type = BeverageType.Water},
                new Beverage {Name = "Beer", Price = 2.75m,
                    Size = 16, Type = BeverageType.Alcohol},
                new Beverage {Name = "Wine", Price = 3.5m,
                    Size = 9, Type = BeverageType.Alcohol},
            };

                return names[Rnd.Next(names.Count)];
            }

            private static BeverageType GetBeverageType(string message)
            {
                BeverageType beverageType;

                Console.Write(message);

                while (!Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), true, out beverageType))
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid beverage type");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.Write("Valid beverage types are: ");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", Enum.GetNames(typeof(BeverageType))));
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.Write(message);
                }

                return beverageType;
            }

            private static string GetName(string message)
            {
                Console.Write(message);
                return Console.ReadLine();
            }

            private static decimal GetCurrency(string message)
            {
                decimal result;
                Console.Write(message);

                while (!decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), NumberStyles.Currency,
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out result))
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid number");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.Write(message);
                }

                return result;
            }
            private static int GetSize(string message)
            {
                int result;
                Console.Write(message);
                while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out result))
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Size");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.Write(message);
                }
                return result;
            }

        }
    }


    {
        public enum BeverageType
        {
            Soda,
            Juice,
            Water,
            Alcohol
        }

        public class Beverage
        {
            public string Name { set; get; }
            public BeverageType Type { set; get; }
            public decimal Price { set; get; }
            public int Size { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"{Name} ({Type}) = {Price:C}";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Break it down to just the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we don't want to have to figure out what your program does by reading a wall of code.

Comment: Have you written this yourself, or are you trying to modify someone else's code?

Comment: I've written it partly myself, I had some help earlier with fixing the menu and crate class initilization. I originially planned for a list in the crate class, but had to change it into an array for project purposes.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? "Doesn't work" is not helpful. Are you getting build errors? Are you getting an exception thrown? Is it not throwing an error but not actually working as you expect? Please give us some more detail (and if possible reduce the code to a minimal example of what is going wrong. In particular you have included a bunch of code that is commented out - is this even relevant?)

Comment: I guess not relevant, I just included it because in the past time of posting I've been told to post the entire thing.  One of the errors I get is  here  {
            if (crate.Count >= MaxItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The crate is full. Please remove an item first!");
            }
            else
            {
                crate.Add(beverage);

I get a compile error operand of >= cannot be applied to method group of type int and beverage does not contain a definition for Add in crate.add line

Comment: You should specify where the problem is occurring, or exactly what is wrong. [Reading how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will show you how to ask a good question, along with the recommendation from @Crowcoder

Comment: Arrays do not have a `Count` property nor an `Add()` method. Please read up on [`Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netframework-4.6.2) for a better understanding of your program errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` doesn't have ***Add*** and ***Remove*** method. We normally inherit from `List`, unless you have specific requirement to use `IEnumerable<T>`.

*For example,*

```
class Crate : List<Beverage>
{
    public new void Add(Beverage beverage)
    {
        if (Count == 24)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The crate is full. Please remove an item first!");
        }
        else
        {
            base.Add(beverage);
        }
    }

    public void Remove(string name)
    {
        Remove(this.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
    }

    public void PrintCrate()
    {
        if (this.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There are no items in the crate.");
        }
        else
        {
            this.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        }
    }
}
```

### Update: Inherit from `IEnumerable<T>`

Since you have to use ***Array*** as per requirement, you will have to implement ***Add*** and ***Remove*** method by yourself. Add is quite easy, but Remove is a little bit tricky.

```
class Crate : IEnumerable<Beverage>
{
    private Beverage[] crate = new Beverage[24];
    private int NumberOfBottles = 0;
    private const int MaxItems = 24;

    public void Add(Beverage beverage)
    {
        if (NumberOfBottles >= MaxItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The crate is full. Please remove an item first!");
        }
        else
        {
            crate[NumberOfBottles] = beverage;
            NumberOfBottles++;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<Beverage> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return crate.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Remove(string name)
    {
        Remove(crate.FirstOrDefault(i =>
            i.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
    }

    public void Remove(Beverage beverage)
    {
        int index = Array.IndexOf(crate, beverage, 0, NumberOfBottles);
        if (index < 0)
            return;
        this.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the element at the specified index of the Beverage array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">The zero-based index of the element to remove.</param>
    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        if (index < NumberOfBottles)
        {
            NumberOfBottles--;
            Array.Copy(crate, index + 1, crate, index, NumberOfBottles - index);
            crate[NumberOfBottles] = default(Beverage);
        }
    }

    public void PrintCrate()
    {
        if (NumberOfBottles == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There are no items in the crate.");
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var beverage in this)
                Console.WriteLine(beverage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only requirement is to use an array instead of a list in the crate class.